# GLMMADMB ERROR: The function maximizer failed (couldn't find STD file)

Tags: r, glm

I am sorry, I know this question has been posted before in various forums but I really wasn't able to find a clear answer to a) what the exact issue is and b) how to resolve it.

My model:

```
secondstagereg_2_nb_mult<-glmmadmb(dv_inc_new ~ 
                                     walkingIMR + log(rev_prev+1) + exp_cominc_prev + exp_countyears_prev + exp_modetargyears_prev +
                                     cv_firstincrease + log(gdp_prev+1) + added_gdppcdistnew + ebrd_prev + gdppc_chngnew + eudum_prev +  
                                     industryclusterdum + mode_newdum + cv_increasefrompartner +
                                     ebrd_chngnew +  
                                     (1|country)  + (1|bvdid) 
                                     ,data=sp_2
                                     ,zeroInflation=TRUE  
                                     ,family="nbinom" 
                                    )
```

The complete error I get:

```
Error in glmmadmb(dv_inc_new ~ walkingIMR + log(rev_prev + 1) + exp_cominc_prev +  :
  The function maximizer failed (couldn't find STD file) Troubleshooting steps include 
     (1) run with 'save.dir' set and inspect output files; 
     (2) change run parameters: see '?admbControl'
In addition: Warning message: running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/glmmADMB/bin/windows64/glmmadmb.exe" -maxfn 500 -maxph 5 -noinit -shess' had status 1
```

-I already tried running version 0.7
-I tried setting mcmc=TRUE, mcmc.opts=mcmcControl(mcmc=50000)
-I tried leaving out a bunch of control variables
All get me the same error. I really dont understand it.

I uploaded the code as well as the corresponding data here (the regression in question starts at line 188, before that is necessary data manipulation):
http://www.wu.ac.at/fileadmin/wu/d/i/iib/data.zip

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I furthermore included the save.dir output files in the uploaded zip file.

Comment: Why comment? You can easily edit and add information in your question anytime.